# how to change user agent in chromium embedded framework in c#?

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefglue

Please help me changing user agent of chromium embedded framework in visual c#.
It uses default chromium agent but i want to change it to use my browser name instead.

Comment: Just for information, I found the current default to be "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" for CefSharp 51.0.0

Answer (score 11):

Use CefSettings.UserAgent.
Also it can be configured via "user-agent" command-line switch.

Comment: Please explain me in detail, step by step.

Comment: CefSettings is class what instance passed at initialization step. Look into samples. You can't initialize CEF without it, so, i'm did not see what should be explained step-by-step. Read samples. Both, C++ and C#. There is easy, and almost same.

Comment: i mean what tag, namespace, etc should i use in my project?

Comment: I'm did not understand what additional details you want. If you are CEF user, you should know about CefSettings class.

Comment: I have done the following changes....... in cef web browser [DefaultValue("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Fire/1.0")]
        public string UserAgent { get; set; }-----------------------------
        and my form----------------    browser.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Fire/1.0";      yet it does not work

Comment: Did you found CefSettings class? It has UserAgent property. It should pass into CefRuntime.Initalize method.

Comment: This dialog is non-constructive. User agent can be changed, as i'm say in my answer.

Comment: "In detail, step by step" instructions are dependent on your local environment and skillset and are therefore chargeable service you have to seek privately. Good luck.

Answer (score 7):

i know its an old question but this might help someone,
use the following code to change user-agent of cef-sharp 3x

```
ChromiumWebBrowser chromiumBrowser;

public Form1()
{

    InitializeComponent();

     CefSettings cfsettings=new CefSettings();
     cfsettings.UserAgent = "My/Custom/User-Agent-AndStuff";
     Cef.Initialize(cfsettings);

     chromiumBrowser = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser("http://whatsmyuseragent.com/")
     {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,

     };


     this.Controls.Add(chromiumBrowser);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use by this code change the user agent in chromium

```
CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
settings.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1";
```

Answer (score 1):

Step by step:

- Download XIlium cefglue and update the dlls. If you need any help in that use http://umaranis.com/2013/10/16/how-to-embed-chrome-browser-in-net-application/
- Open your xilium cefglue application.
- In solution explorer open CefRuntime.cs
- There will be a public static void Initialize(CefMainArgs args, CefSettings settings, CefApp application, IntPtr windowsSandboxInfo) method, inside that method write  settings.UserAgent = "Sonal";
- Rebuild and run the application.
- In the browser give the the following url: http://whatsmyuseragent.com/
- You can find the Useragent as Sonal

Hope this helps